# 3D Camera looking at arbitrary point, but never rolling to do so

Tags: 3d, xna

(In C#/XNA 4.0)

I have Vector3 cameraPosition, Vector3 targetPosition

I want to have my camera look at the target, always 'facing' it, but **never rolling**

So roll always is neutral, to view the target the camera always either adjusts pitch or yaw

I've tried countless combinations of methods and information I find here and on the web but I haven't found anything that works properly.  I think my issue may be my 'Up' vector (which I've tried .Up, 1,0,0, 0,1,0, 0,0,1)

When I move my camera I do:

```
  CameraPosition += moveSpeed * vectorToAdd;
  UpdateViewMatrix();
```

UpdateViewMatrix() is.. well, I've tried everything I have seen.  At most simple...

```
   View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(CameraPosition, targetPosition, upVector);
```

Where upVector has been Vector3.Up, 1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1, or other more 'proper' attempts to get my actual up vector.  This sounds like it's probably my problem..

This should be dead simple, help!

Comment: As long as the 3rd arg of the CreateLookAt() is Vector3.Up (which is 0,1,0), the view matrix will not apply any roll. It is simply impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ends up I was confusing myself somewhere about what things should look like and what I was actually considering "up" in my worldspace.  I had to use up vector of (0, 0, 1) and things worked great

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Y-up world space, absence of roll means that camera side vector has Y = 0. You have to get your view direction vector (`normalize(targetPos - cameraPos)`), and get such side vector that it's orthogonal to view and has Y = 0, in other words `view.x * side.x + view.z * side.z = 0`, `view.y = 0`. This is a simple 2d perpendicular, `side = normalize(vector3(-view.z, 0, view.x))`.

After you have the side vector, you can get `up = cross(view, side)` and construct the view matrix.

Depending on the handedness of your coordinate system, you may need to negate the side vector.

Note that there's a singularity at `view.y = +-1` (side is a zero-length vector); this is because the roll is not defined for this pitch angle - any roll value gives the same transformation.

Comment: On further reflection, for any sane LookAt function, this is equivalent to using an up-vector (0, 1, 0).